# How do I serve a page over https using expressjs?

Tags: node.js, https, express

I'm new to nodejs/expressjs. Could someone please explain how to to serve a page over https?

I have to ask this question another way, stackoverflow is complaining that my post is mainly code?

Here is the error dump:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    ^
```

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'get'  at Object.
>   (/home/john/startup/docm/w2.js:21:5)  at Module._compile
>   (module.js:456:26)  at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:474:10)  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)  at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)  at Function.Module.runMain
>   (module.js:497:10)  at startup (node.js:119:16)  at node.js:901:3

And here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var   fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

var options = {
    ca:   fs.readFileSync('csr.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
    key:  fs.readFileSync('key.pem')
};


var server = require('https').createServer(options);
var portNo = 8889;
var app = server.listen(portNo, function() {
  console.log((new Date()) + " Server is listening on port " + 8888);
});

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
 app.use(express.static(__dirname));
 console.log('app.get slash');
 var buf = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync('index1.html'), 'utf-8');
 response.send(buf.toString('utf-8'));

});
```

I'm new to nodejs/expressjs. Could someone please explain how to to serve a page over https?

Comment: don't redefine the variable app after you've created the express app: `var app = server.listen(...)`

Comment: It's also documented here: http://expressjs.com/api.html

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your application is that you're overriding your Express instance with your HTTPS instance. This is how it is properly done:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  ca: fs.readFileSync('csr.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(443, function() {
  console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 443');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 console.log('app.get slash');
 var file = fs.readFileSync('index1.html', {encoding: 'utf8'});
 res.send(file);
});
```

These were the errors in your code:

1. Instead of passing Express to HTTPS you overwrote Express with the HTTPS instance.
2. You did not pass your Express application to your HTTPS instance.
3. The Express `static()` middleware should be served outside of specific request handlers.
4. You passed a buffer to another buffer to set its encoding although `readFileSync()` already has an encoding option.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I just love the way people are willing to share and help others not so experienced get up and running. I'll compare your answer to how I was trying it to make sure I fully understand where I went wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried this, and although the server runs. I can't get it to serve the index1.html page. My client browser just sits there, and eventually after maybe 1 minute, it says "Server not found" (Firefox), or "No Data Received" (Chrome)
I can create an http server fine. But my https server will not serve the page. I don't know what my gap in knowledge is. Is it something I need to configure on the client side?
openssl genrsa -out server-key.pem 1024
openssl req -new -key server-key.pem -out server-csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -in server-csr.pem -signkey server-key.pem -out server-cert.pem

Comment: I got it working. Thanks again for your help. I really appreciate it.